# Connection reset by 15.x.x.x 2215, Remote end hung up unexpectedly, Early EOF, index-pack failed

Tags: git, git-clone

I am using Visual studio 2008 command prompt to clone a git repo. After downloading 6.12GiB of data, I am getting the below error.

```
D:\git>git clone -c http.postBuffer=2147483648 git@git.x.x.x.net/y/z.git download
Cloning into 'download'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5053615, done.
remote: Counting Objects: 100% (5053615/5053615) done.
remote: Compressing Objects: 100% (948773/948773) done.
Connection reset by 15.x.x.x port 2215), 6.12GiB | 807.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

*I did set the http.postBuffer=2147483648 to the above and the http.lowspeedlimit=0, http.lowspeedtime=999999.*

What might be the issue in downloading the repo, any resolution on the above issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection timed out. (6.12GiB at 807KiB/s is more than two hours; even if it was moving faster than 807KiB/s before then it's still a long time. Also, what's in this repo that it's 6+ gigs?)

You have a couple options here:

1. Use a faster connection! (I know, easier said than done.)
2. Blobless clone: `git clone --filter=blob:none <url>`. This will get the trees and commits now, and then get blobs (file contents) as necessary.
3. Shallow clone: `git clone --depth=0 <url>` (or deeper if you want). This will get the `depth` most recent commits now, but no prior history.
4. Get someone who already has a copy to make you a bundle with `git bundle`. This is a somewhat complicated procedure, but if there are a lot of people trying to clone this very large repo then a bundle can help streamline the process.